# Azure Media Services Encoding Job Callback to URL

Tags: azure-media-services

Using only the REST API, I am able to upload a file to Azure Media Services from my local machine and start an encoding job. Then I need to poll the job for status to see when it is done. But, what I really want is for Azure Media Services to send a request to my callback URL when it is done. Is there way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at our Notifications features which supports WebHooks.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/media-services-dotnet-check-job-progress-with-webhooks

It integrates well with Azure Functions also - if you want to host your callback in Azure Functions and just leverage the WebHook trigger in there. 
We have some examples of doing that up here:
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/media-services-dotnet-functions-integration/tree/master/101-notify-webhooks

Comment: The documentation at [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/media/operations/notificationendpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/media/operations/notificationendpoint) is incorrect. It states that for `EndpointType`, "The only valid value is: AzureQueue = 1". This is not true, as I discovered when I reverse-engineered the SDK from the source code on GitHub. The valid values are `None = 0, AzureQueue = 1, AzureTable = 2, WebHook = 3`. I lost several hours to this problem.